# Splitting text file into sentences

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split a text file into sentences, using punctuation as a delimiter. The code I have so far works but the delimiter is being printed out on a line by itself. How can I keep the punctuation together with the sentence?

```
import re
string = ""
with open("text.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        for l in re.split(r"(\. |\? |\! )",line):
            string += l + "\n"
print(string)
```

Example output:

```
This is the flag of the Prooshi — ous, the Cap and Soracer
. 
This is the bullet that byng the flag of the Prooshious
. 
This is the ffrinch that fire on the Bull that bang the flag of the Prooshious
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually were simple, you adding \n(newline character) on every iteration, so, for example you splitting `Kek.` it will add to string variable `Kek\n` and then `.\n`.
You need to do something like this:

```
with open("text.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    for l in re.split(r"(\. |\? |\! )",line):
        string += l
    string += '\n'
```